# git diff on shell scripts

Tags: git, gitweb

I want to add shell scripts (".sh") into a git repository. But when viewing them in the git web interface it recognises them as binary files. Therefore I can not view them online or see diffs between different commits.

Is there a way to tell git how to handle these shell scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell git that these files are text files using the [`.gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes.html). The simplest way is to say that all `.sh` files are text. Put this in a `.gitattributes` file in your repository root:

```
*.sh    text
```

This might not fix your issue, though. When you say 'git web interface', do you mean 'Github'? I couldn't find any documentation about whether Github uses the `.gitattributes` file when determining the file type. But this will let you run `git diff` on your local repository, at least.

There's some more documentation about `.gitattributes` [in the **Pro Git** book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes). That approaches things in the other way, though: making binary files available as text, for meaningful diffs.